# random.shuffle doesn't shuffle

Tags: python, random

I'm building a deck of cards that has shuffling function. I'm using random.shuffle, but it is not shuffling at all. When I run the following codes, the whole deck is printed out in good order. Please have a look, thanks!

```
import random


class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def show(self):
        print("{} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit))
        return self.value


class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        for s in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]:
            for v in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(s, v))
                print("{} of {}". format(v, s))

    def show(self):
        for cards in self.cards:
            print(cards.show())

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)
        return self.cards

    def draw_card(self):
        return self.cards.pop()


deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()
```

Comment: Your code seems to work for me? Can you please explain further what part that isn't working? And show examples for us how to reproduce it.

Comment: this code works. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Is there a chance that you're confusing the print-statements inside of `build()` with the actual shuffle of the deck?

Comment: @Hampus Larsson, I think you are right about the confusion. I thought since I have a return statement for `shuffle()`, it would print out the shuffled deck.

Comment: @Kentta Well, it is returning your shuffled deck. However, you're not "catching" it or printing out the results of that return. If you do `deck.shuffle()[0].show()` then it will launch the `show` method on the first value inside of the newly shuffled deck. However, the `random.shuffle` method changes the list in-place, so you don't have to return anything in your own method. You can just fetch the shuffled deck in `deck.cards`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code, the console output messages you are seeing in good order are created from the `self.build()` function, if you call deck.show() at the end, you will see the shuffled messages.

```
deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()
deck.show()
```

Comment: `deck.show()` helps, but can you please explain why the return statement in `shuffle()` won't show the shuffled items?

Comment: as comments by Hampus Larsson already explained, those print functions are executed before shuffle function is executed in your code, so those are showing message in order.